# Rebuild jar file from class files

Tags: java

I want to edit a single file of a compiled Java application. I've extracted the contents of this application using a program I wrote in Java. I then decompiled the class file I needed to edit, made my changes, recompiled the class, and replaced the old file with this new one.

I would now like to rebuild the project with these newly made changes. I've read about this "jar cfv" command, however I'm not too sure if it's what I'm looking for. I tried it but received an error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile cfv
```

Here is the extractor I wrote (to give you the idea of the extracted project):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class Main {

private static int directoryCount = 0;
private static int fileCount = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
        String regex = "extract ";

        if (nextLine.startsWith(regex)) {
            String[] split = nextLine.split(regex);
            String sourceFilePath = split[1];

            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFilePath);

            if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
                System.err.println("Invalid file.");
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("Beginning extraction.");

            try {
                extract(sourceFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Finished extraction. Extracted a total of " + fileCount + " files and " + directoryCount + " directories.");
            fileCount = 0;
            directoryCount = 0;
        }
    }

    scanner.close();
}

private static void extract(File sourceFile) throws IOException {
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(sourceFile);
    Enumeration < JarEntry > enumEntries = jar.entries();

    File destination = new File(sourceFile.getParentFile(), sourceFile.getName().replace(".jar", ""));

    if (!destination.exists()) {
        destination.mkdir();
    }

    while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry file = enumEntries.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Extracting: " + file.getName());

        File f = new File(destination, file.getName());

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdir();
            directoryCount++;
            continue;
        }

        if (f.getParentFile() != null && !f.getParentFile().exists()) {
            f.getParentFile().mkdir();
            directoryCount++;
        }

        f.createNewFile();

        InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

        while (is.available() > 0) {
            fos.write(is.read());
        }

        fos.close();
        is.close();

        fileCount++;
    }

    jar.close();
}
}
```

The project is extracted into a folder containing everything that is in the original jar file. Now how do I rebuild the project?

Comment: Why not just open the jar with a zip viewer like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)?

Comment: `jar cf something.jar thefolder/` you might want to read this [tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: You probabiy want to use an IDE for writing\compiling\building your code. Look into NetBeans or Eclipse.

Comment: @MTCoster WinRAR and 7Zip (and any others that I know of) require system administrator password to install, which I do not have.

Comment: @RC. I've already tried that, and as I said in the original question, I receive this error: Error: Unable to access jarfile cfv

Comment: If you don't have administrator access, try using [the PortableApps version of 7-Zip](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable).